# Copy REF CURSOR to a temporary table

Tags: oracle, database-connection

Is there a quick way to flush REF CURSOR into a temporary table in oracle

CURSOR size will vary between 5K to 100K rows

currently I am using a for loop, but its very slow

There is no way to change the OUT parameter for SOME_FUNCTION_CALL function.

```
DECLARE
v_return SYS_REFCURSOR;
VAR_A varchar2(100);
VAR_B varchar2(100);

BEGIN 
 v_return := SOME_FUNCTION_CALL();
LOOP
FETCH v_return into VAR_A,VAR_B
EXIT WHEN v_return%NOTFOUND
          INSERT INTO temp_table(a,b) values (VAR_A,VAR_B);
END LOOP;
CLOSE v_return;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: It might be faster to populate a collection and then for a `forall` bulk insert; possibly in chunks to reduce memory usage of that's going to be an issue. Is this a GTT or a real table? Maybe you only really want a collection anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not.

You could potentially make the code more efficient by doing a `BULK COLLECT` into local collections rather than doing row-by-row fetches.  Something like

```
DECLARE 
  TYPE vc100_tbl IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);

  l_return    SYS_REFCURSOR;
  l_var_a_tbl vc100_tbl;
  l_var_b_tbl vc100_tbl;
BEGIN
  l_return := some_function_call();

  LOOP
    FETCH l_return
     BULK COLLECT INTO l_var_a_tbl, l_var_b_tbl
    LIMIT 100;

    EXIT WHEN l_var_a_tbl.count = 0;

    FORALL i IN 1 .. l_var_a_tbl.count
      INSERT INTO temp_table( a, b )
        VALUES( l_var_a_tbl(i), l_var_b_tbl(i) );
  END LOOP;

  close l_return;
END;
```

That will reduce the number of context shifts taking place between the SQL and PL/SQL engines.  But depending on your definition of "very slow", it seems unlikely that context shifts are your most pressing problem.  Were I to guess, I'd wager that if your code is "very slow" for most definitions of that term, the problem is likely that the query that is being used to open the cursor in `some_function` is slow and that most of your time is being spent executing that query in order to generate the rows that you want to fetch.  If that's the case, you'd want to optimize the query.

Architecturally, this approach also seems rather problematic.  Even if you can't change the definition of the function, can't you do something to factor out the query the function is executing so that you can use the same code without calling the function?  For example, could you not factor out the query the function calls into a view and then call that view from your code?